# How to remove seconds from a date and time stored in a variable

Tags: vba

I've got a date like this one in a variable and I want to remove the seconds and milliseconds from it.

26/08/2021 19:56:30.844

I know I can remove milliseconds using Split(Start_Time_Value, ".")(0) but not sure what I can do to also remove the seconds. Can somebody help? Thanks

Comment: @Nathan_Sav that still contains the seconds on it.

Comment: Yes, sorry, like this `format(Split(Start_Time_Value, ".")(0) ,"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm")`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav That worked exactly like I expected. If you submit that as an answer I can select it as the answer to my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just format the string after, like so

`format(Split(Start_Time_Value, ".")(0) ,"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm")`